# json.dump() does not take a list of dict

Tags: json, python-3.x

I have problems writing a json file
I've a list of dict, with inside the dict another dict (that has a list). the code is

```
import json
results.append("text": [line_1, line_2,...],
               "date": "today"
               "meta": {"field_01": line_3,
                        "field_02": [item.keys() for item in dict_list_of_dict],
                       }})

with open("file_name", "w", encoding="utf-8") as f:
    json.dump(results, f)
```

The error message:

> TypeError: Object of type 'dict_items' is not JSON serializable

Any suggestions how to solve this??

thanks,

Andreas

=====
Traceback:

```
> TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-182-acb18c0e0c91> in <module>
      1 with open(os.path.join("policy-text-MiddleEast-all2010-2020-entityPERSON" + ".json"), 
      2           "w") as f:
----> 3     json.dump(result_new[0], f)

/usr/lib/python3.6/json/__init__.py in dump(obj, fp, skipkeys, ensure_ascii, check_circular, allow_nan, cls, indent, separators, default, sort_keys, **kw)
    177     # could accelerate with writelines in some versions of Python, at
    178     # a debuggability cost
--> 179     for chunk in iterable:
    180         fp.write(chunk)
    181 

/usr/lib/python3.6/json/encoder.py in _iterencode(o, _current_indent_level)
    428             yield from _iterencode_list(o, _current_indent_level)
    429         elif isinstance(o, dict):
--> 430             yield from _iterencode_dict(o, _current_indent_level)
    431         else:
    432             if markers is not None:

/usr/lib/python3.6/json/encoder.py in _iterencode_dict(dct, _current_indent_level)
    402                 else:
    403                     chunks = _iterencode(value, _current_indent_level)
--> 404                 yield from chunks
    405         if newline_indent is not None:
    406             _current_indent_level -= 1

/usr/lib/python3.6/json/encoder.py in _iterencode_dict(dct, _current_indent_level)
    402                 else:
    403                     chunks = _iterencode(value, _current_indent_level)
--> 404                 yield from chunks
    405         if newline_indent is not None:
    406             _current_indent_level -= 1

/usr/lib/python3.6/json/encoder.py in _iterencode(o, _current_indent_level)
    435                     raise ValueError("Circular reference detected")
    436                 markers[markerid] = o
--> 437             o = _default(o)
    438             yield from _iterencode(o, _current_indent_level)
    439             if markers is not None:

/usr/lib/python3.6/json/encoder.py in default(self, o)
    178         """
    179         raise TypeError("Object of type '%s' is not JSON serializable" %
--> 180                         o.__class__.__name__)
    181 
    182     def encode(self, o):
```

Comment: this may help
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48374667/object-of-type-dict-items-is-not-json-serializable

Comment: Is that your actual code? The error message implies the data contains the result of ``dict.items``. ``item.keys()`` would produce the message akin to ``TypeError: Object of type dict_keys is not JSON serializable``.

Comment: Thanks, it worked with your modifications. And I was just thinking I had written such a nice condensed code ;-)

Answer (score 2):

`item.keys()` returns a [*view object*](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict-views), which the `json` module doesn't know what to do with. Turn it into a list: `list(item.keys())`.