# Fail to pass dict data to jquery. Error display as: Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list)

Tags: javascript, jquery, django, django-views, django-templates

I have issue on reading data that pass from a Django template in jquery .js file.
The data in my Django view:

```
print({0}, {1}\n'.format(init_data[1], type(init_data[1])))) // this will print: 'Counter({'pass': 15, 'fail': 2}), <class 'collections.Counter'>

context = {"data":init_data[1].items()}
return HttpResponse(template.render(context, request))
```

In my index.html template I'm able to read the data out as such

```
{% block content %}
    <h3> {{data}} </h3>      // this printed dict_items([('pass', 15), ('fail', 2)])

    <div class="tab">
        <button class="tablinks" onclick="openResult(event, 'TabForm')" id="defaultOpen">Form</button>
        <button class="tablinks" onclick="openResult(event, 'TabChart', '{{data}}')">Statistic</button>
    </div>

    <div id="TabChart" class="tabcontent">
        {% include 'result/tab_statistic.html' %}
    </div>

{% endblock %}
```

In result/tab_statistic.html, I want to use the 'data' as dynamic data for a chart in jquery, but the 'data' seem not readable in jquery script as I get bug complaining: (index):18 Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list

Here is my simple jquery script just to show the data is not readable when called from function openResult() above

```
function openSummary(evt, tabName, a ) {
    if (typeof(a)==="undefined") a = "None";
        console.log('CHECK a=' + a);
    return
```

It seems to be it don't allow 'data' to be passed directly as the way I do because if I replaced the {{data}} with any argument 'abc' , it just working. Pls gives me a suggestion how to fix this. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

rather than doing

```
onclick="openResult(event, 'TabChart', {{data}}'
```

How about:

```
<script>
var data1 = {{data}}

# then call your function by addEventListner..something like below:

document.getElementById("myBtn").addEventListener("click",
</script>
```

**Update**

```
import json

# context = {"data":init_data[1].items()}
data_dict = init_data[1].items()
data_json = json.dumps(data_dict)
context = {"data": data_json)

return HttpResponse(template.render(context, request))
```

Also,

```
onclick="openResult(event, 'TabChart', {{data}}')"
```

was `'` after {{data}} a typo? Because the error says syntax error, maybe this was the cause.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, I need to stick to the existing <button class="tablinks" onclick=... cause the above snipped is just part of the whole script, I need to stick to existing. It seems neither allow list or dictionary to pass through from html to jquery. I'm newbie on django

Comment: Haven't doen that way, but I updated answer with json. Maybe when you use json.dumps, you can use it readily in your js function.

Comment: Thanks ha-neul, the ' is a typo. For your suggestion, I get error'Object of type dict_items is not JSON serializable'. May I know why is that so? In the mean time.. I'll do some google for this error.

Comment: try  remove``.items()``` https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48374667/object-of-type-dict-items-is-not-json-serializable

Comment: Thanks for the link, I can't removed just the items() cause that will print CHECK a=["pass", "fail"] . I tried another solution with data_json = json.dumps(list(data_dict)), it printed the data I want : CHECK a=[["pass", 15], ["fail", 2]]

Comment: I have one further question on this, ha-neul. May I know how can I access the 'a' to get each the pass and fail ,and 15  and 2? the normal for loop  line :     for i in a:
        print ('i=' + i)

Comment: try something like: ```a[0][1]``` and ```a[1][1]```

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't recognize this kinda format a[0][1]. Pls let me know if you have else suggestion. I'll check this post over the time. Also, I will mark accept your suggestion and you have done a great deal helping me solve my initial problem. Thanks ha-neul.

Comment: Thanks! maybe you can open another question about it. someone more knowlegable shoulb be able to help.

Comment: yea, probably. I'll try do some research first. Thanks ha-neul. You have do me a great favor. Have a great day ahead!